# angular2 navbar component injection

Tags: angular, css-selectors, components, navbar, code-injection

I am creating a demo web application using Angular 2.

This application is made up from a main page with a navbar and (for now) 2 modules with components for that navbar. So each module should show its buttons on the navbar in the main screen.

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible using non-advanced Angular.

Unfortunately i am not able to set the selector of multiple different components to the same value or include not one but two attributes in the html without getting a 'Template parse error'. In addition i am also not able to include for example two span-tags in the main html each holding the selector attribute for the different modules for Bootstrap css breaks and creates a multi-line navbar. Again here i want to stay as close to native Bootstrap as possible.

So my question is basically how to go about creating a Bootstrap navbar and 'injecting' navbar items (buttons, search bar, etc.) from different components/modules?

Module 1:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: '[ticket-navbar]',
  templateUrl: 'ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['ticket.component.css']
})

export class TicketComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Module 2:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: '[user-navbar]',
  templateUrl: 'user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The html from the main page which should show the navbar items from included modules:

```
    <!-- navbar menu items -->
    <div [collapse]="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline" ticket-navbar user-navbar>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- navbar menu items -->
```

Comment: is the nav bar the same in each module?

Comment: Only the main application contains a navbar. Each and every module contains navbar menu items it should inject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you're trying to do if you use components instead of attribute directives:

```
<div [collapse]="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline">
        <ticket-navbar></ticket-navbar>
        <user-navbar></user-navbar>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then simply change your selectors:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ticket-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['ticket.component.css']
})

export class TicketComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'user-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas,

Thank you for your swift reply.

I started out this way, however due to the additional html this generates the Twitter bootstrap markup breaks. That is why i moved to attribute selectors which solve this problem.